# Android ActivityRecord in proc activity list using null instead of expected ProcessRecord

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, launchmode

My app frequently crashes when using launchmode 'SingleTop'. Removing the SingleTop fixes this but I'm curious as to why exactly this is happening and if there is something I am missing when using this launchmode?

```
ActivityRecord in proc activity list using null instead of expected ProcessRecord
```

Comment: Please post the error and stacktrace from the logcat. There should be nothing about `singleTop` launch mode that causes your app to crash.

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Comment: not really, just changed it back since there wasn't much info in the stack trace aswell

Comment: I got this error when an Activity has singleTask, switched back to singleTop and it went away.

Comment: I had received error error found activityRecord {5a1574b u0 com.android.settings/.Settings t-1 f} in proc activity list using null instead of expected process record{ca28780 3429:com.android.settings/1000} fixed it by removing android:taskAffinity from manifest

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, mine might be a bit different then yours. My problem was that I had an EditText which I was using for the user to input a numerical value, and I was using `Integer.parseInt(s.toString())` and I found the app would crash if the user would input a number 11 digits long, exceeding the integer cap. Hope I could help!

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem, but in my case I received an exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment already added:
>   SomeFragment{d5fc212 #23 id=0x7f090063 SomeFragment}